# Android NDK: compiling fuse-zip library for Android application

Tags: android, c, compilation, android-ndk, fuse

I need important information to me: is it possible to compile the fuse-zip library with Android NDK (native C code) so to call it from an Android Java app? 
I need to have zip files mounted as a filesystem.
My main concerns are:

1. Will it compile?
2. Will it work on the user devices? (I mean the "root" question).

The Linux version of this library works mounting the filesystem inside a ZIP file to an existing (preferably empty) folder on the user system. I can create a hidden temporary folder on the user device for this purpose, but is the linking process the library does a "root" operation? Will it fail or succeed on the user devices?

Comment: It is very likely that, out of ~7 billion people on the planet, you are the only one who cares about using `fuse-zip` on Android from an app. Hence, in all likelihood, the only way you will get answers to your questions is if you try it yourself. If I had to guess, it might compile but will not work, simply because `fuse-zip` is not a library designed to be embedded in an application. Moreover, it is unclear what advantage `fuse-zip` would have to an Android SDK application over simply using the existing ZIP file classes.

Comment: @CommonsWare So please, tell me if those ZIP classes are able to mount a Zip file as a filesystem or they just unzip the content.

Comment: Neither. They give you access to the ZIP file's contents. This is no different than in standard Java, where these classes have existed for over a decade.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, still unclear to you what advantage fuse-zip would have?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `fuse-zip` would be a net negative to an Android application. Using native code adds significant development overhead, particularly if that native code is not ported to run on all Android CPU architectures (ARM, x86, MIPS). There are certainly plenty of cases where native code is essential. Accessing the contents of a ZIP file would not appear to be one of them. If you think it is, edit your question to provide a rationale, so others perhaps can suggest alternative solutions that would not require native code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to have the zip file mounted as a filesystem. I added this information to the question, in case fuse-zip itself is not self explanatory.